# PHPmailer multiple attachments only sends first

Tags: php, upload, phpmailer

When trying to send multiple files with phpmailer I am using this statement to check if at least one file has been uploaded:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) or move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2) or move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile3']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile3)) {
```

and use this code to attach the files

```
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile, 'file', 'Uploaded file');
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile2, 'file2', 'Uploaded file 2');
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile3, 'file3', 'Uploaded file 3');
```

however it only sends the first selected file, and does not send the other ones that may come after it. It looks like the if statement just stops whenever it found a condition that is true.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact ... if statement stops when first condition match ... so build a new logic

e.g.

```
<?php 
   $success = array();
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) $success[] = $uploadfile;
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2)) $success[] = uploadfile2; 
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile3']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile3)) $success[] = uploadfile3; 

   if($success) {
      // Your code here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AddEmbeddedImage please try with addAttachment.

```
  $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile,  'Uploaded file');
  $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile2, 'Uploaded file 2');
  $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile3,  'Uploaded file 3');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with PHPMailer.; it's just basic understanding of expression evaluation in PHP.

If you have a true result on the first part of the `if` condition, it does not need to evaluate the rest of the condition to know it will evaluate to true overall, so the other functions will never be called.

Check each file separately and it will work.